# Is it redundant to say "a spelling bee contest"?

Tags: redundancy

A "spelling bee" is an expression usually used to describe the spelling contest, but not necessarily. With that in mind, is it be considered redundant to call it a "spelling bee contest" or a "spelling bee competition"?

Comment: What have you discovered on the internet, say?

Comment: Bearing in mind that *spelling bee* is more familiar to Americans than Brits, it's possible a writer would simply add *contest/competition* to make the meaning crystal clear to all. But given that 90% of *everything* we say is "redundant", why pick on this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, the term *spelling bee* is very common, but it is rarely seen or heard immediately followed by the terms *contest* or *competition*. This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spelling%20bee,%20spelling%20bee%20competition,spelling%20bee%20contest&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,spelling%20bee;,c0;.t1;,spelling%20bee%20competition;,c0;.t1;,spelling%20bee%20contest;,c0) shows that the phrase standing alone is nearly a hundred times more prevalent.

Most US speakers would consider the terms *contest* or *competition* to be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

There is an entry in the OED which explains the term originated in the US farming community, where groups of neighbours would get together to help one another. They would, for example, hold 'an apple-bee' to gather in the apples; a harvest-bee, a quilting-bee etc. The term was an illusion to the social character of the insect. Spelling-bee derived from similar groups getting together to hold a spelling competition.

I have no idea if they still have them in the USA, but it is certainly a dated concept in Britain. Though I guess what we are doing here on this site might be termed a 'literacy-bee'.

Comment: Spelling bees are indeed still around (at state and national levels, even) and very popular in the United States.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet They probably provide the same sort of social function as pub quizzes which are very popular in Britain.

Comment: In a way; but also more than that. It is an annual [national event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripps_National_Spelling_Bee) broadcast nationwide on ESPN.